# How do you add multiple unique Excel files in one long file? (Python)

Tags: python, excel

There are many posts on how to add xlsx files, this is not the same.

I have 189 excel files each representing unique data. I want to add all this into one xlsx file as one long thread, for easier readability. There are no rows/columns to merge/concat, each column/row is unique. Each file has multiple rows and columns.

It can all be in one sheet or each file can be in its own sheet where the sheet name == file name.

I need this for easier readability so I dont have to open 189 different files, but scroll through one.
Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason for Python?

Answer (score 0):

For that you should consider Pandas Library.

First,

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

The you should import Pandas and Glob

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
```

Then you should start mapping your necessities.

```
def All_XLSX_in_One():
    Excel_path = 'Your_Worksheets_Path'
    all_files = glob.glob(Excel_path + "/*.xlsx")
    li = []
    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    Excel_path_final = Excel_path + '/' + ' ALL_EXCEL.xlsx'
    frame.to_excel(Excel_path_final, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The code above should save an Excel worksheet with all the xlsx files in 'Your_Worksheets_Path' merged.

It works better if they all have the same columns.

Run it by calling your def.

```
All_XLSX_in_One()
```

Comment: Instead of `df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0)`, I would use `df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0).T.reset_index().T`. With this modification, the individual excel worksheets are framed one below the other.